# Slicing a python dataframe from a string date column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, date, slice

I am trying to slice a dataframe based on their str date values.
I only want to keep records of the last 15 days.

When I try this

```
df_master_recent_date= df_master['Datetime_col'] > (datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("15day"))
```

I get error : `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

When I convert the `df_master['Datetime_col']` to date

```
df_master_recent_date = datetime.strptime(df_master['Datetime_col'],'%Y%M%D') > (datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("15day"))
```

I get error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series`

At the beginning of the code I convert the entire dataframe to str with this `df_master= df_master.astype(str)`

Date format in the column is `'21/02/2022  12:21:00'`

I understand the errors, and the second error likely to be resolved with a for loop which I need to figure how to construct, however, does anyone knows how to get this working without a for loop, or with the for loop if one line is not possible.
Thank you.

Comment: try pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime_col'])

Comment: @Vincent Many thanks, it seems that is not complaining about datatype now, but  I am getting an error ValueError: day is out of range for month. Any idea why? Once again, many thanks!

Comment: Try to specify the date format ! And if it still does not work, it is due to your data

Comment: @Vincent, you are right, I have  0 values in some columns, which I need, to differentiate  those with date and without. I might have to create a df with only those with dates and then get recent ones. Many thanks.